# Calling on Checkboxes in a usercontrol onpostback C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a usercontrol that has some checkboxes in it.  On postback i want to read the state of the checkboxes.  Where i am having trouble is i don't know how to call on a control inside of a user control.

I have a lot of features in each usercontrol which is why i did it this way. I have the controls working properly i just don't know how to identify them in my c# on postback so i can then print the results somewhere. I am using masterpages and a update panels as well. checkboxes are set to autopostback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FindControl()` method to find out controls within user control.

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox )userControlID.FindControl("childControlId")
```

Comment: I cant except your answer fast enough

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one of two ways; first, you can make the controls public, allowing them to be seen as members of the UserControl from outside it. Second, the Controls property of the UserControl is always public, and will contain the CheckBoxes. You'll have to search for them by type and name; Linq can help:

```
var checkbox = myControl.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(chk=>chk.Name == "checkBoxName");
```